# getUser() only returning 0 now; was working yesterday?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have an app where the Facebook Login was working great as of yesterday.  I switched to AWS EC2 to get a bigger server for some capacity planning for today.

Unfortunately, the Facebook Login is no longer working.  In particular, after getting the access_token from the JavaScript authorization, the getUser() call returns only 0.  The code is below.

Since the server is the only thing that has changed (and IP) is there some configuration related to my server that I'm missing/unaware of?

```
if(isset($_GET["access_token"])) {
    $access_token = $_GET["access_token"];
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    ));
    $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if($user) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

            $user_name = $user_profile["name"];
            $user_email = $user_profile["email"];
            $fb_uid = $user_profile["id"];
            $fb_access_token = $access_token;

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error';
            header($status_header);  
            header('Content-type: application/json');

            echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Facebook Exception'));
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error';
        header($status_header);  
        header('Content-type: application/json');

        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Facebook user does not exist', 'access_token' => $access_token, 'user' => $user, 'fb' => $facebook));
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try in another webbrowser. Maybe it's a cache or cookie issue?

Comment: Tried three different browsers

Comment: Do you use the same domainname aswell? A facebook application is limited to the domain you've supplied in your settings.

Comment: Yes, it's the same domain.  I pointed the DNS entry to the new server last night.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the 500 response is too glaring to bypass. This is not a 500 error. It ought to be either a 401 or a 200 with a nice error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible ideas:

1. The Curl library you are using on that system is not working properly. Try doing the call from the shell using some of the examples that are scattered around FB's site.
2. I once moved an app to a different server and had FB API calls inexplicably not work -- on the *exact* same code, after an rsync -- despite updating the new server IPs to be in our whitelist. I surmise that either the Facebook Developer App whitelist updating feature is broken or that IP was banned permanently from all of Facebook's APIs. If all else fails, try moving to a different EC2 instance in a different availability zone to see if it works there.

p.s. At the time, I emailed Facebook's "contact me if you have any problems" developer rep to check if the IP updating might be broken, but of course I got no response from the helpful team over there.

Comment: Thanks, this made me dig deeper in the Curl library.  Turns out it was the path for the CA Certs!  For now I modified base_facebook.php to also capture the Curl error code 77 in the makeRequest() function.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET values are the correct ones and that the url you are accessing the site from is set as the site url and site domain on the application settings page.

Otherwise verify the PHP SDK versions are the same and the PHP versions are the same. This may help narrow down the problem.

Comment: I did that (and triple checked it) and everything is accurate.

Comment: http://www.edition01.com/.  I've hidden the FB Login button via CSS for now so users don't try to sign up and get an error.

Comment: FYI, if you have access to a Javascript console and are comfortable with that, you can enable the FB Login button by running the following: `$("p.hidden").removeClass('hidden');`

Comment: Yes I was able to log in fine and see that /register.php is throwing a 500 error. What version of PHP SDK are you using? Same on both?

Comment: facebook-php-3.0 on both servers.  One thing I just realized is that the new server I created on EC2 is running PHP 5.3.6 and my older server was running 5.2.17.  Are there any known issues with the FB SDK between the two?

Comment: v.3.1.1 is the latest - try the newest sdk version.

Comment: Also, to clarify, as you can see above, the 500 is explicitly set by me when no user is found.

Comment: Just upgraded to v.3.1.1 and still no luck.  Is there a good way to test whether the call to create a new Facebook() object worked successfully?